# PHP Replace function not working with Internet explorer 8

Tags: php, html, replace

I have a little problem with my website, it is a free classified ads website where people upload photos to their ad, etc.

Problem: my upload script work perfectly with all my computers, but when I check in my Error_Log it show that a lot of people can't upload their picture (it does upload in the temp folder but when I use the rename function to copy it in the ad folder it does not work and say: No such file blah blah blah. So I found someone who has the problem of uploading and realize that internet explorer was the problem.

My version is :

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

which seem to work fine and the version he is using is:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.

which does not work.

Is there any reason why my function do work in Internet Explorer 9.0, Firefox, and Chrome but not in IE 8?

**EDIT**
(This is the code for transfering the files from temp folder of the user to the ad folder:)

```
mkdir("./users/".$this->Username."/".$Id, 0755);
mkdir("./users/".$this->Username."/".$Id.'/thumbnail', 0755);
$Files_List = explode("@",$_POST['Files_Names']);
for($i = 0;$i < count($Files_List);++$i)
{
    if($Files_List[$i] != "")
    {
        rename('./users/'.$this->Username.'/temp/'.$Files_List[$i], './users/'.
        $this->Username.'/'.$Id.'/'.$Files_List[$i]);
        rename('./users/'.$this->Username.'/temp/thumbnail/'.$Files_List[$i], './users/'.
        $this->Username.'/'.$Id.'/thumbnail/'.$Files_List[$i]);
    }
}
$dir = './users/'.$this->Username.'/temp/';
foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v)
    unlink($v);
$dir = './users/'.$this->Username.'/temp/thumbnail/';
foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v)
    unlink($v);

echo '<script>window.location = "./message.php?Message=Publier";</script>';
exit(0);


Error message:


[17-Oct-2011 12:31:17] PHP Warning: rename>(./users/francois/temp/thumbnail/2590cd9217.jpg ,./users/francois/186/thumbnail/2590cd9217.jpg ) [href='function.rename'>function.rename]: No such file or directory>in /home/kesimard/public_html/Montreal/publier.php on line 70

Line 70 = rename('./users/'.$this->Username.'/temp/thumbnail/'.$Files_List[$i], './users/'. $this->Username.'/'.$Id.'/thumbnail/'.$Files_List[$i]);
```

Comment: The file do upload in the temp folder because I can see the thumbnail on the page before posting the ad. So the problem is the rename function

Comment: Why did you delete your other identical question? ([here, for those who can see it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797859/php-replace-function-only-working-in-certain-browsers)

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this? Even in internet explorer 8 I can see the thumbnail photos, but when I press Post submit the rename function isnt working...

Comment: This is not an IE or Firefox issue. The issue is with the the directory structure/permissions on the server

Comment: Well it does work with internet explorer 9 , google chrome , firefox, safari. So I don't know what to do now. I tried everything I could.

Comment: Not sure if that's just a copy/paste error, but there's a space after your filename in the error message.  Did you try trimming the filename? `rtrim($Files_List[$i])`

Comment: using rename() to handle uploaded files is the wrong way to go. What you want is `move_uploaded_file()`, which has extra sanity/security checks to close a few security issues with PHP's upload file handling.

Comment: @MVS omg, I think you were right, I think there was a space at the end of the file name. I tried using rtrim function and I downgraded from internet explorer 9 to 8 and I tested it. I don't know if having the latest version of 8 is different then other versions of 8 but mine is working right now. I'm waiting for a friend to get online and test it for me ( the guy that had the error )

Comment: @Joseee I don't think you have realised nor has anyone here yet mentioned to you, that PHP is a server-side script which processes the php files and then returns a pure HTML page to the browser. The browser NEVER reads PHP code, so you are mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a filesystem issue than a browser issue.  Before the `rename()` functions, try adding this:

```
if (!file_exists('./users/' . $this->Username . '/' . $Id)) {
  mkdir('./users/' . $this->Username . '/' . $Id);
}
if (!file_exists('./users/' . $this->Username . '/' . $Id . '/thumbnail')) {
  mkdir('./users/' . $this->Username . '/' . $Id . '/thumbnail');
}
```

Comment: I do call mkdir function ( look in the post above I edited it sorry forgot to put that line)